# cannot read property '0' of undefined JSON

Tags: javascript, json, image, gallery

I'm trying to make an image slider that changes the image 'displayMain' every few seconds. My problem is that when I call the displayMain function in setInterval, I continuously get a 'cannot read property 0 of undefined' error. Even when I use the hardcoded value of jsonData[i].name, I receive the same error. The value gets passed in displayThumbs just fine, however. Does anyone know why I can't retain the values in displayMain but can do so in displayThumbs?

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var mainDiv = document.getElementById('main');
    var descDiv = document.getElementById('main-description');
    var gallery = document.querySelector('#main-img');
    var ul = document.querySelector('ul');
    var li;
    var i = 0;
    var displayThumbs;
    var thumbName;
    var current = 0;
    var images = [];

    function displayMain () {
        var data = images[i];
        gallery.src = 'img/' + data[0];
        descDiv.innerHTML = '<h2>' + data[1] + '</h2>';
    }

    function displayThumbs () {
        for (i = 0; i < images.length; i += 1) {
            var data = jsonData[i].name.replace('.jpg', '_thumb.jpg');
            // thumbnails use dom to make img tag
            li = document.createElement('li');
            thumbs[i] = document.createElement('img');
            var createThumbNail = thumbs[i].src = 'img/' + data;
            thumbs[i].setAttribute('alt', data);
            thumbs[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
                alert(createThumbNail);
            });
            ul.appendChild(thumbs[i]);
        }
    }

    // success handler should be called
    var getImages = function () {
        // create the XHR object
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        // prepare the request
        xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function () {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                // good request ...
                jsonData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i += 1) {
                    var data = [];
                    data.push(jsonData[i].name);
                    data.push(jsonData[i].description);
                    images.push(data);
                }

                displayMain();
                displayThumbs();
                setInterval(displayMain, 1000);
            }
            else {
                // error
            }    
        });

        xhr.open('GET', 'data/imagedata.json', true);
        xhr.send(null);    
    };

    // setInterval(getImages, 2000);
    getImages();
    // displayThumbs();
});
```

Comment: What is the `setInterval(displayMain, 1000)` supposed to be doing? Unless the image itself changes on the server, this will do absolutely nothing.  Also, have you tried stepping through with a debugger and checking the value of `images` after the for loop runs?

Comment: I am trying to get setInterval to go to the next image but I can't do so if I can't retain the jSonData[i].name value in the displayMain function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your `displayMain` uses whatever value `i` is at the time, and `i` never gets incremented, so it'll be equal to images.length after the for loop in `displayThumbs`. `displayThumbs` increments it itself, so you won't ever go beyond the end of the array.

In your comment, you mentioned that you want to cycle through the images. This should work a bit better:

```
function displayMain () {
    var data;

    // wrap around to the first image
    if (i >= images.length) {
        i = 0;
    }

    data = images[i];
    gallery.src = 'img/' + data[0];
    descDiv.innerHTML = '<h2>' + data[1] + '</h2>';
    i++;
}
```

Personally, I would use a private `i`, just in case another function reuses the same variable:

```
function displayMain () {
    var data;

    // wrap around to the first image
    if (displayMain.i >= images.length || isNaN(displayMain.i)) {
        displayMain.i = 0;
    }

    data = images[displayMain.i];
    gallery.src = 'img/' + data[0];
    descDiv.innerHTML = '<h2>' + data[1] + '</h2>';

    // move to the next image
    displayMain.i++;
}
```

This attaches a variable named `i` to the function `displayMain`. It will update this variable each time it is called, and no other function will use the same `i` variable.